# What should the name of our main chatroom be?

Tags: discussion, chat

Every Stack Exchange site (Not all) main chatroom has a unique name that is related to the main site itself.

For example:

- Super User: Root Access
- Gaming: The Bridge
- IoT: Chat of Things
- Unix & Linux: /dev/chat

and etc

What should our main chat room be named?

[The Real Essential Questions of Every Beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223675/311917)

> 5. Whats an interesting name for the chat room?
>    Every site comes with its official chat room. This is created automatically and can be reached from the Site Switcher on the top left. The chat room is the third place of your community, after main and meta. It is like the lounge where everybody can get together to discuss, complain and have fun. Personalizing this space to reflect your community and what you are, is one of the small steps to take towards building an active and engaged community.
>    Try to get a few ideas up, discuss and vote on them. The name could be something esoteric in your field, or something that every person may understand. Whichever it may be, go ahead and start the discussion!

Comment: Well, there is "Certified Fresh", but Rotten Tomatoes is already using it…

Comment: List of chat rooms: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315289/282094 with unusual names.

Answer (score 12):

### The Pudding

It's [where the proof is](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/origin-of-the-proof-is-in-the-pudding-meaning).

Comment: I love it! Plus 1 from me.

Answer (score 11):

Proposal: **Tautology**

Really, all this *proving stuff* business isn't telling us anything we didn't already know. It's all just implications of the axioms. We are but explorers in the space of tautological statements; proof assistants are equipment.

Any on-topic discussion is talking about tautology.

Comment: @HenryWHHackv3.0b I'll tentatively rename it now, because it can always be renamed later. A one-vote lead after five days probably isn't enough for an accept, though. (If I'm being honest, I'm rooting for a different name; not saying which.)

Comment: Do you want to wait until the private beta ends?

Comment: @HenryWHHackv3.0b Maybe. It's important for people to feel like the chat room is theirs, though, so… I could ask in the room, actually. Can't believe I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 9):

One off-the-cuff idea: ***Trusted kernel***

Comment: @GuyCoder: The desiderata for the name of the *chat room* are very different  from the name of the whole site — see the examples given in the question.  The name of the site is public-facing, and indeed should be very careful to avoid all possible misunderstandings — that’s a major reason why most newer stackexchange sites don’t have custom names.  But the chatroom names are mainly seen by established users, and rarely used out of the site’s context, so their names don’t have to bear so much communicative weight and can be a bit more light-hearted.

Answer (score 5):

Proposal: **The Library**

Proof assistants almost inherently use libraries to collect, organize, and reuse definitions, constructions, and proofs. And while libraries are also a big part of most programming languages, "The Library" has a much more pencil-and-paper feel to me that is reminiscent of mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

Proposal: **Equality Reflection**

Two words that open Pandora box.

Answer (score 3):

Proposal: **The Theorealm**

Just a off the cuff pun, we’ll see if it catches on here.

Answer (score 1):

Proposal: **The Resolution**

It's both a process in reasoning and [something official](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resolution):

> : a formal expression of opinion, will, or intent voted by an official
> body or assembled group

.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: The Reasoned Conversation

Suppose you are participating in a discussion related to some question, or a broader issue related to proof assistants, and you want to suggest taking it to chat. With a name like this you could say "Let's take this to The Reasoned Conversation."

For me that sets a good kind of tone, and reminds people that this site is about reasoning.

Comment: Going off your idea, what about "The reasoning room"?

Answer (score -13):

Idea: **Leanssistant**

[lean](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lean) Is the most common tag so This looks good.

Comment: Well, ok, but it's just one particular language, so I'm not sure it reflects that the chat will be open to any programming language (that relates to proof assistants).